# postgresql performance - group by after sub query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I'm learning PostgreSQL and thinking one case as below:
if I have a user table, columns are user_id, user_name, year, month, day, transaction_amount. And table index is (year, month, day, user_name)

if we have 1 billion users, can I write my query as following :

```
select t1.user_name, sum(t1.transaction_amount) total_txn
(
-- sub query
select year, month, day, user_name, transaction_amount from user where year=2021 and month = 3 and day = 5 
) t1. 
group by t1.year, t1.month, t1.day, t1.user_name
order by total_txn desc
limit 10, 10
```

Can I say that the sub query should be get smaller dataset so my group by and order by can be done on smaller dataset ? Or the whole query have to full table scan ?

Thank you

Comment: Run [explain analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-explain.html) on your query. Then rewrite the query without the sub-query and also run the explain. Compare the difference. Note: `Explain analyze` actually runs the query to completion, so it may take some time.

Comment: Don't store `year, month, day` in separate columns. Instead, use a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP`.